# is it possible to use the page object pattern in nightwatch with mocha test runner?

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests, mocha.js, nightwatch.js, pageobjects

i want to implement the page object pattern in my nightwatch tests and use mocha at the same time.

My test class looks like this

```
module.exports = {
'Create Subscription' : function (browser) {
    var createPage= browser.page.createSubscriptionPage();
    var subscriptionName = '_test_nightWatch',
        subscriptionDescription = 'description';

  it('should create a  subscription', function(browser){
        createPage.navigate()
             .waitForElementVisible('@nameField', 20000)
             .setValue('@nameField', subscriptionName)
             .setValue('@descriptionField', subscriptionDescription)
             .expect.element('@nameField').to.have.value.that.equals(subscriptionName)
             browser.expect.element('@descriptionField').to.have.value.that.equals(subscriptionDescription)
        browser.end();
    });
}
```

};

i updated my json file to

```
"test_runner" : {
    "type" : "mocha",
    "options" : {
        "ui" : "bdd",
        "reporter" : "list"
    }
}
```

it starts the server but nothing runs

I've seen issue on this online but none that have been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out ...

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var nightwatch = require('nightwatch');

describe('Create Subscription', function() {
     var subscriptionName = '_test_nightWatch',
         subscriptionDescription = 'description';

it('should create a subscription', function(browser){

    var createPage= browser.page.createSubscriptionPage();
        createPage.navigate()
             .waitForElementVisible('@nameField', 20000)
             .setValue('@nameField', subscriptionName)
             .setValue('@descriptionField', subscriptionDescription)
         .expect.element('@nameField').to.have.value.that.equals(subscriptionName)
        browser.end();
    });
});
```

**EDIT**: Formatted text properly